# SwiftUI Function declares an Opaque return type, inserting two buttons in one View?

Tags: swift, return, swiftui

I would like to build a simple SwiftUI ContentView.swift. In this App's view pane it would contain two buttons with their images implied. I thought about adding a function for each button one by one, then allowing SwiftUI to show each element. I have viewed some questions related to the return type, although it is confusing me as to where you would add a return type if I only have a Button(). My code is very short, is it easy to see where I went wrong where I did not include the return?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body : some View {
        func Button1(){
        Button(action: {
         print("Here is a bit of information.")
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "info")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 600)
        }
        }
        func Button2(){
        Button(action: {
            print("You have erased it.")
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "trash")
            .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 426, height: 620)
        }
        }
            }
```

I am hoping that these two buttons will appear on the screen's first view, and I may then edit the action's they will both take after I understand the placement within the code. Thank you for your insight :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you would do this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("Here is a bit of information.")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "info")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 600)
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("You have erased it.")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 426, height: 620)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. One last thing, After completing this statement in the 2nd to last bracket of the code I tried adding > return Button() But I still ran into an issue " Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate" How would I end this code? What is the last piece to include for the "return" line at the end?

Comment: Why would you use return inside the body? What you need to do, like the above code shows is to nest Elements inside Stacks you would never need a return statement. I really don't understand what you're doing. You don't need functions for the Buttons. Update your question with the new code so we can see what's wrong

Comment: Ah I see. Yes I was able to get the code running eliminating the additional functions. The question is resolved, Thank you Frankenstein and @PedroCavaleiro

Comment: @Tomato_code If you found the answer helpful then consider upvoting and marking as the right answer.

Comment: Yes I did, Thanks. I have too low reputation points for my vote to be seen as an upvote xD but I did upvote. Thank you again user Frakenstein.